# Apache & Nginx location query

Tags: apache, plesk

Within Plesk I am looking to apply a couple of location directives.

One to only show video files if served by the local referer (blocking direct access) and the other to pass  X-Robots-Tags

Presently, it only executes one of these directives, depending upon the order I put them in.

My question is, can I combine these into one directive? If not, is it possible for these both to work side by side?

Here's the code:

```
location ~* \.(mp4)$ {
add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet, nocache";
}

location ~* \.(mp4)$ {
valid_referers mysite.co.uk www. mysite.co.uk;
if ($invalid_referer) {
return 403;
}
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: The same location directive ("location ~* \.(mp4)$ {") can only occur once. All directives that referr to it, need to be placed in the same block